# How to use typedef and define

Tags: c++

I write this code to print on the output the current line and the file name:

```cpp
#ifdef _DEBUG
                char buffer[10000];
                std::string const full_path = __FILE__;
                auto const basename = full_path.substr(full_path.rfind('\\'));

                sprintf(buffer, "Line:%d %s \n\n", __LINE__, basename.c_str());
                OutputDebugStringA(buffer);
#endif
```

I don't know much about typedef and define, is possible to convert this part of the code below, into a typedef or define?

I mean a way to call it in just a single line.

```cpp
                std::string const full_path = __FILE__;
                auto const basename = full_path.substr(full_path.rfind('\\'));
```

Comment: `ifdef` and `define` are part of the C/C++ preprocessor. `typedef` allows you to create an alias for a type (default or user-defined type). If you are using GCC, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/. ifdef falls under "conditoinals", and define, falls under "macros."

Comment: @TedLyngmo: to avoid constructing one more `std::string` object? The temporary 10KB array is bad enough :)

Comment: @chqrlie I read the question again. I hope I understood it correctly this time :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I mean a way to call it in just a single line.
>
> ```
>             std::string const full_path = __FILE__;
>             auto const basename = full_path.substr(full_path.rfind('\\'));
> ```

Generally, that's what functions are for. The only problem is the use of the macro that depends on what file it's in (`__FILE__`). Luckily, C++20 allows us to not need a macro:

```
#include <source_location>

std::string
current_source_file_base(const std::source_location& location
                             = std::source_location::current())
{
    return std::filesystem::path(location.file_name()).filename();
}
```

Now, you can call that in a reusable fashion:

```
std::string source_file = current_source_file_base();
```

---

Alternative that doesn't require `std::string` and thus won't allocate dynamic memory... but may give partial filenames if they contain escaped directory separators. This is a problem with your original code as well. The limitation could be fixed by more complex logic, or by using `std::filesystem::path_view` which is proposed but not part of the standard. (Please don't use escaped directory separators in source file names).

```
constexpr std::string_view
current_source_file_base(const std::source_location& location
                             = std::source_location::current())
{
    char separators[] = {
        std::filesystem::path::preferred_separator,
        '/',
        '\0',
    };
    std::string_view path = location.file_name();
    std::size_t pos = path.find_last_of(separators);
    return pos == std::string_view::npos
        ? path
        : path.substr(pos + 1);
}
```

---

All that said, I recommend to **not** remove the directories from the path because that will make it impossible to distinguish `dir1/file.cpp` from `dir2/file.cpp`.

---

Prior to C++20, you would need to use a function-like macro.

Comment: Yes, this should be the go-to version!

Comment: Even more `:` gratification :)

Comment: @chqrlie I heard you like `:`, so I provided a non-allocating version with even more `:`

Comment: `:` feel better in pairs, but you could use a tail call: `return path.substr((pos + 1) * (pos != std::string_view::npos));`

Comment: @TedLyngmo No problem, edit is appreciated. Leaving out the included headers is just laziness on my part.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `std::string` construction this way:

```
        char buffer[1000];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "Line:%d %s\n\n", __LINE__,
                 strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') + 1 : __FILE__);
        OutputDebugStringA(buffer);
```

If must make it a one liner:

```
    char buffer[1000]; snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "Line:%d %s\n\n", __LINE__, strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') + 1 : __FILE__); OutputDebugStringA(buffer);
```

Here is a more general approach:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DEBUG_TRACE(s)  do { \
        char buffer[1000];   \
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "Line:%d %s %s\n\n", __LINE__, \
                 strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') + 1 : __FILE__, s); \
        OutputDebugStringA(buffer); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define DEBUG_TRACE()
#endif
```

Put the above definitions is a header file and add traces in your code:

```
int test(int a) {
    int res = 0;
    DEBUG_TRACE("entering test");
    if (a % 3 == a % 5)
        res = 1;
    DEBUG_TRACE("leaving test");
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A platform agnostic way to get the basename of a file would be:

```
#include <filesystem>

auto basename = std::filesystem::path(__FILE__).filename();
```

or, if you prefer it as a `std::string` object instead of a `std::filesystem::path` object:

```
auto basename = std::filesystem::path(__FILE__).filename().string();
```

Comment: This is definitely a more idiomatic approach. *c++: so many classes, so little time...*

Comment: @chqrlie Yours is purer in some sense though - and perhaps more approachable to OP.

Comment: Yes but it smells too much of C, whereas yours is a better fix for `:` addiction: *oxycolon*, the c++ version of [oxycodone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxycodone).

Comment: @chqrlie :-D :-D :-D Never heard that before. I'm bringing that to work on Monday :-D